# FluentValidation, Autofac, and child collection of interfaced objects

Tags: generics, autofac, fluentvalidation

I'd like to validate an object that contains a child collection of type: `ICollection<IEntity>`

There are multiple classes that implement IEntity.  I have a validator for each of those classes.  They all inherit from ValidatorAbstract.

How can I assign an appropriate validator in the parent class to each of the children objects inside the collection?

I use Autofac to inject dependencies.  I'm guessing that I need to use this method:

```
RuleForEach(n=>n.ChildCollection).SetValidator(container.Resolve<?>)
```

However, SetValidator has no context of each object's type.

Comment: What information DO you have to resolve service you want?

Comment: Autofac contains the binding between some CustomValidator and IValidator<ChildEntity> where ChildEntity : IEntity.  I can inject Autofac's container into the parent validator class if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found the answer I was looking for.  The key is to create a custom validator class that derives from NoopPropertyValidator and give it the Autofac container (or other IOC container)

```
public class EntityCollectionValidator<TEntity> : NoopPropertyValidator
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _container;

    public EntityCollectionValidator(IComponentContext container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> Validate(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationFailure>();

        var collection = context.PropertyValue as IEnumerable<TEntity>;
        if (collection == null) return results;

        foreach (var entity in collection)
        {
            var interfaceType = typeof (IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(entity.GetType());
            if (!_container.IsRegistered(interfaceType)) continue;

            var validator = _container.Resolve(interfaceType) as IValidator<TEntity>;

            if (validator != null)
                results.AddRange(validator.Validate(entity).Errors);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

And in the validating class, the way to instantiate this is to do this on a collection of generic resource:

```
    RuleFor(n => n.ChildCollection)SetValidator(new EntityCollectionValidator<IChild>(container));
```